# Teamviewer 9: Apply a Password from a .reg-file

Tags: registry, teamviewer

I'm currently trying to apply a Password from a reg File for Teamviewer 9.

This is my Registry File so far (cut out the Hex Values because they don't really matter for this question):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version9]
"Security_PasswordStrength"=dword:00000001
"PermanentPassword"=hex:#####
"MultiPwdMgmtIDs"=hex(7):#####
"MultiPwdMgmtPwdData"=hex(7):#####

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version9\AccessControl]
"AC_Server_AccessControlType"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version9\DefaultSettings]
"Autostart_GUI"=dword:00000001
"HostInfoDialog"=dword:00000000
```

This Registry File works for Teamviewer 11 (without the Version9 Path of course :) ), but in Tv9 the Passwords don't work, but they get applied (also visible under Options > Security).

As soon as I set the Passwords manually under "Options > Security" the passwords work, but the value in the Registry remains the same.

I've also tried to do a full export/import in the teamviewer options, but the result stays the same.

Could someone please tell me what I'm missing/doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've set the same password on multiple devices and noticed the values for PermanentPassword were different. Perhaps the encryption is based on the machine, or on "PK" registry key (private key)?

Comment: I have no Idea, I still haven't found an answer to this aswell, But I've also tried to export the whol settings from one machine and apply them to another machine, with no success.